# Sorting a std::map without deleting and reinserting entries

Tags: c++, sorting, stdmap

I have a std::map where the key is a pointer to a class that has a priority() method and the value is just an int. The map has a compare function that compares keys by their priority(), which is an integer member variable of the key class.

At some point I want to change key priorities, e.g. key A was priority 1, key B was priority 5, after the change key A's priority is now 5 and key B's is 1. Just to emphasise that the objects the keys point to are not changing, jusr one of the object member variables is.

So I want the std::map to reflect this change. Is there a simple way of 'sorting' the map other than saving all the key/values, clearing the map, then inserting the saved values, and hence get a newly sorted map?

Comment: yep, `std::map` doesn't support changing the key comparisons, you'll have to clear and reinsert

Comment: The question is confusing. The two statements "the key is a pointer to a class" then "key's value is just an int" are mutually exclusive. They cannot both be true. The map's key is either a pointer, or it is an int. It cannot be both, at the same time (a variant with a suitable comparator is possible, of course, but that's obviously not the case here, whatever the case here might be). Try to pretend that you're talking to someone who has not seen a single line of your code, and explain the question to this person.

Comment: The best (but this depends on one's definition of "best") that can be done is to avoid reallocation by extracting, fixing and re-inserting in the following manner: https://godbolt.org/z/s11s9nv5P

Comment: That extract / insert (using move) is neater that the existing soluton I had, thanks.